# simulation of non-homogeneous poisson processes

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, algorithms, censoring, poisson-process

When simulating non-homogeneous (time-dependent hazard $\lambda(t)$) Poisson processes, we can use thinning [1] to generate jump times $t \in [0,t^0]$:

1. initialize $t = 0$
2. generate $u_1 \stackrel{d}{\sim}U(0,1)$
3. set $t = t -\frac{1}{\lambda_u}\log(u_1)$
4. generate $u_1 \stackrel{d}{\sim}U(0,1)$ independent of $u_1$
5. if $u_2 \leq \lambda(t)/\lambda_u$ then deliver $t$
6. goto 1

where $\lambda_u \geq \lambda(t), \forall t \in [0,t^0]$.

My question: What do you do with samples $t>t^0$? The context of this question is censoring, say we have censoring time $t^0$ are the samples $t>t^0$ then censored or are they not generated with the right probability?

[1]: Lewis, Peter A., and Gerald S. Shedler. "Simulation of nonhomogeneous Poisson processes by thinning." Naval Research Logistics (NRL) 26.3 (1979): 403-413.